# Ajax request laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send a request to the server using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "eslam",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,

    data: {is_admin : 1},
    success: function () {
        alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 

        var id = $('#Category').val();
        var info = {id: id};
        $('#sub').load('eslam', info);
    }
});
```

But I get this error:

> **unauthorized error 401**

Comment: 401 means page not found , configure your route please. 

or call your function in the url like    url: "<?php echo action('TestController@getMyfunction' );?>"

Comment: Most likely missing CSRF token.

Comment: More code please on Laravel Side not Just JS

Comment: did you try with   url: "<?php echo action('TestController@getMyfunction' );?>"   ?

Comment: @ EslamKalash: Please post the code that is responsible for sending the CSRF token, since it's not part of the AJAX request you posted. @PunitGajjar 401 means [unauthorized](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) as the question states.

Answer (score 0):

Are you validating the request data? If so, you must set `return true` in the `authorize()` method.

Comment: i don't validate data just use  authentication to check user is admin or not

Answer (score 0):

Do you used CsrfToken ????
if you used CsrfToken, you should send CsrfToken

Answer (score 0):

u might use middleware to check if login or something else, like:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['login'],
    'prefix' => ‘elsam',
    'namespace' => ‘urNameSpace',
], function(){
     //
});
```

remove the middleware or remove part of ur url from the group.

Comment: i can't remove middleware  because Authentication and i want  to check this user is admin or not